# Convert units in Activities

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-gnome, activities-overview

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME 42.5.

It used to be called Dash but now I don't know what is evoked when I press `super`. Top left corner says Activities so let's go with that.

I'm looking for some utility, or some resources that'd help me write one, when I press `super` and type, say, `convert 2 inch to cm`* it'll display the output.

This crazy idea came to me after using MacOs (for work) which... can do that. I do have internet, and I have terminal app, and I spend most of my time in the terminal... but wouldn't it be nice to have a use for these Activities?

*I'm also aware that there's a popular cmdline tool called `convert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Gnome Activities actually do the unit conversion. Discovery was accidental and can't say that results' display is the best... but it's there.

Solution? Make sure that in the "Search" settings you have "Calculator" enabled and **just type query into the activities**. For example, image below shows searching for "2 inch to cm" and a results from Calculator that it's 5.08.

[image: gnome activity 2 inch to cm equals 5.08]

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line app called `numbat`, which can convert all kinds of physical units.

Download the latest debian package from https://github.com/sharkdp/numbat/releases, and install it.

[image]
A web interface is available at https://numbat.dev

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?